# Print a group of lines if they contain specific strings

Tags: command-line, bash, awk

I have a file (`file 1`) that looks like that:

```
>C 0
0   4231aa, >A6_03412... at 1:4226:1:4240/95.44%
1   4240aa, >A5_01600... *
>C 1
0   4159aa, >FG1_03697... *
>C 2
0   3942aa, >A3_03045... at 1:3942:1:3945/96.50%
1   3945aa, >A4_03199... *
2   3942aa, >A7_02989... at 1:3942:1:3945/92.11%
3   3941aa, >A6_03202... at 1:1:1:1/96.35%
```

I consider the part between the two `>C` as subgroup. So, for example this is a subgroup

```
 >C 0
 0  4231aa, >A6_03412... at 1:4226:1:4240/95.44%
 1  4240aa, >A5_01600... *
```

I have then another file (`file 2`) containing strings inside the subgroup:

```
A6_03412
A4_03199
.....
```

I want to print all subgroup that contain the string in `file 2`. So considering that in `file 2` I just have the above mentioned strings the output should be:

```
>C 0
0   4231aa, >A6_03412... at 1:4226:1:4240/95.44%
1   4240aa, >A5_01600... *
>C 2
0   3942aa, >A3_03045... at 1:3942:1:3945/96.50%
1   3945aa, >A4_03199... *
2   3942aa, >A7_02989... at 1:3942:1:3945/92.11%
3   3941aa, >A6_03202... at 1:1:1:1/96.35%
```

This is tough one, any suggestion how to do that with a bash script?

Comment: While this *can* be done in Bash and Awk (because they're Turing-complete), they're probably not the best tool to do that. I'll try a solution in Python.

Comment: wow..Turing-complete is a new term for me

Comment: @DavidFoerster `awk` is very much capable of doing this. I agree that bash, while capable, is needlessly complex here but `awk` is a different matter.

Comment: @terdon: I never said that Awk is incapable. I also don't know *that* much about the Awk language, so I might be missing something, but as I see it, it would help to have more complex data structures at hand than Awk offers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A two-part solution using Perl and grep:

```
perl -pe 's/^>C \d+$/\0$&/' file1 | grep -zFf file2
```

- Since `>C <some number>` separates the groups, I match that and insert a ASCII nul character (`\0`) ahead of each group.
- Then I can take advantage of `grep`'s ability to deal with NUL-delimited lines (`-z`), while reading patterns from a file  (`-f file2`).

With awk, I'd do something similar, by using `>C` as the record separator and printing a NUL before each record:

```
awk -v RS='>C ' '{printf "\0>C %s", $0}' foo | grep -zFf ba
```

Comment: Thanks very much. The perl option works perfectly, but the awk solution prints all subgroup and not only the one containing the strings in file2. I would actually prefer a `awk` solution.

Comment: @efrem on the sample set you have given, it only printed C0 and C2 for me. Do you have a larger set I can experiment on?

Comment: Only in Linux (and Unix) can you provide such a simple one-line solution! Amazing.

Comment: how ca I hopen the perl output as txt?

Comment: @efrem Redirect the output to a text file? `perl ... | grep ... > output.txt`.

Comment: @muru, yes I did, but I can see it only as binary

Comment: @efrem oh, damn - you need to strip out the nul characters: `perl ... | grep ... | tr -d '\0' > output.txt`.

Comment: you are the master!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
with open('file_1') as f_1, open('file_2') as f_2:
    f_1_subgroups = f_1.read().split('>C')
    f_2_lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f_2]
    for subgroup in f_1_subgroups:
        for line in f_2_lines:
            if line in subgroup:
                print '>C' + subgroup
```

Here we have first split the "file_1" into subgroups using the delimiter `>C`, then we have searched for the lines of "file_2" in the subgroup. If found, we have printed the subgroup.

Using list comprehension:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
with open('file_1') as f_1, open('file_2') as f_2:
    f_1_subgroups = f_1.read().split('>C')
    f_2_lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f_2]
    print ''.join(['>C' + subgroup for line in f_2_lines for subgroup in f_1_subgroups if line in subgroup])
```